# I have a table with a checkbox in each table row. I want to show all checked tr rows in different background color using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have  a table with a checkbox in each table row. I want to show all checked tr rows in different background color using jquery 
checkbox name in tr is

`MSPAdministration[0].isHold,MSPAdministration[1].isHold`
`MSPAdministration[2].isHold`

etc

Comment: A glimpse of your HTML will help.

Comment: and any attempt at writing the code too, because SO isn't a code writing sweatshop :p